# Is there a way to apply FFT to an unevenly spaced time series?

Tags: python-3.x, fft

i have two series X and Y. X contains time values and Y contains a real function values for those times. I wish to perform FFT of the Y signal in python. The problem is that X is unevenly spaced: X(n+1)-X(n) /= constant. Is there a known way to apply FFT to such data ?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What the syntax is to perform an FFT in python? What you will get out? Why is the uneven-ness relevant to your question?

Comment: as long as your sample points in series Y are evenly spaced just feed that into a FFT call ... no need to be concerned with series X since its implied in series Y as long as Y is evenly spaced ... if Y is not evenly spaced then make it so

Comment: You are looking for a non-uniform FFT (NUFFT). Googling “python nufft” yields multiple packages that do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new evenly spaced set of samples, Y', by interpolation.  Then FFT Y'.  How well this works depends on well the form of interpolation you choose matches the physics that produced your original Y,X data.